# Can I add an LWC component from Scratch Org to a managed package?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, scratch-org, dev-hub

I am a newbie and I am faced with the following task: to set a namespace prefix for my organization, as well as to create a managed package, develop an LWC component and add it to a managed package. I created a new **Scratch Org** and created my own component there. I also have separate organizations **Developer Edition** (with the namespace installed) and **DevHub** (where the managed package is created). Do I understand correctly that my component from Scratch One needs to be moved to DevHub in order to be able to add it to a managed package? Or can it be somehow linked to DevHub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paradigm differs depending on whether you are building a *First-Generation Managed Package* or a *Second-Generation Managed Package*. While 2GP is preferred for new projects, you should confirm which style of package you're being asked to created.

Since you already have the Dev Hub and packaging org or namespace org in place, you'd need to do next...

### First-Generation Managed Package

For a 1GP, you would need to

- Create a package in your packaging org.
- Retrieve the metadata from your scratch org into version control.
- Deploy the metadata from version control into your packaging org.
- Add the metadata to the package in the Packaging UI in the packaging org.
- Upload a beta or released package version from the Packaging UI.

Check out [Package an AppExchange App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/isv_app_development/isv_app_development_packaging) on Trailhead.

### Second-Generation Managed Package

For a 2GP, you would:

- Retrieve the metadata from your scratch org into version control.
- Create a package in the Dev Hub using the `force:package:create` SFDX command.
- Create a package version using the `force:package:version:create` SFDX command, which uploads metadata directly from your source control.
- Optionally, promote the package version to allow it to be installed in a production org.

Check out [Package Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model?trail_id=sfdx_get_started) on Trailhead.